# How do I handle a growing Controller Class? 

Tags: php, model-view-controller, library-design

```
$object_cin = new CIO( ); 
$object_cin->invoke( $_POST[ 'model' ] );

class CIO
{
    private function invoke( $model )
    {
        switch( $model ) 
        {
            case 'user_try':
                $model = new MUserTry();  
                $this->send( $model->invoke( 1 ) );
                break;
            case 'user_new':
                $model = new MUserNew( new IUniversals() , new IText(), new IMessage() ); 
                $this->send( $model->invoke() );
                break;
            case 'user_exist':
                $model = new MUserExist( new IUniversals() , new IText(), new IMessage() );  
                $this->send( $model->invoke() );
                break;
            case 'tweet':
                $model = new MTweet( new IUniversals() , new IText(), new IMessage() );
                $this->send( $model->invoke() );
                break; 
            default:
                echo "Incorrect Ajax Type provided";
        }
    }
    private function send( $string )
    {
        echo "|P|" . $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not making your cases a class method (with an handler for when it doesn't exist)?

Comment: What do you mean by a handler for when it does not exist?

Comment: something like `if(!method_exists('calledmethod')){ header('Location:404.php');exit;}`

Comment: I ended up getting rid of the dependency injection pattern and factory pattern...to reduce this class by half...I also pulled out file calls in to another class....I still don't get what you are saying...are you saying to use header to make class / object calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it will grow, and become impossible to maintain.

First of all, what is with the generic `Control` class? A website is supposed to have multiple controllers (I am assuming that it is somehow related to MVC, because that's where the term "controller" comes from), usually 1 controller per one "page" (granularity may change, depending on architectural pattern).

Next problem is the big `switch` statement. Each of the `case`'s there should be a separate method in a controller. You end up repeating parts of code, just because of the design mistake.

Comment: Nevermind...I removed all but ajax calls...please look at new code I posted....fits nicely into one file....File Calls are handled by another class.

Answer (score 1):

You've run straight into the [Fat Controller](http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2008/12/03/the-fat-controller/) antipattern.

A controller is meant to be little more than glue logic.  It passes the data from the request (GET, POST, WHATEVER) to whatever model knows how to handle it, formats whatever result the model returns and assigns it to the view to render.

At least that's what's supposed to happen.

Far too often, the developer fills the controller with the application logic, leaving the models as little more than CRUD objects for doing database access.  This is not the way to develop an MVC application.  Models are supposed to be "domain experts".  As well as storing the data the application is working with, they are also meant to know what that data means, what is valid behaviour for given sets of data, and so on.  This makes the model reusable, loosely coupled and highly coherent.  You can use a rich model with many different view/controller combinations without difficultly.

If the application logic is in the controller, then you're stuck using that controller to execute the application logic, or even worse, you'll end up copying and pasting the same code into different controllers.

If the controller is full of application logic, then that's a sure sign that you need to rethink your design and refactor